# LazyVStack with animation causing menu to disappear

Tags: swiftui

If an action in the menu rendered in LazyVStack causes the item wrapping it to disappear, when the item appears again via some other data change, the menu won’t display. This only happens if 1) the views are displayed in an LazyVStack and 2) the visibility change happens with some animation.

Here’s a small toy example:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import CoreMotion

struct Item: Equatable {
    var id: String
    var archived = false
}


struct ItemView: View {
    let item: Item
    let onChange: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("item \(item.id)")
            Menu {
                Button {
                    onChange()
                } label: {
                    Text("Switch")
                }
            } label: {
                Text("menu")
            }
        }
    }
}

class GroupOfItem: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [Item] = [
        Item(id: "a"),
        Item(id: "b")
    ]
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var toggle = false
    
    @StateObject private var groupOfItem = GroupOfItem()
    
    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: $toggle) {
            Text("toggle")
        }
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(groupOfItem.items.filter { $0.archived == toggle }, id: \.id) { item in
                    ItemView(item: item) {
                        withAnimation {
                            groupOfItem.items[groupOfItem.items.firstIndex(of: item)!] = Item(id: item.id, archived: !item.archived)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tapping on “switch” in the menu will cause the item to disappear with some animation, and switching the toggle will make it appear. However, notice that the menu is gone.

Is there a way to workaround this? VStack is not performant enough, List has its own quirks and without the animation the experience feels very jarring.

Answer (score 0):

Could you work around this with a `contextMenu`? While not identical, it seems to work in OK in a `LazyVStack`

```
struct ItemView: View {
    let item: Item
    let onChange: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("item \(item.id)")
            Text("menu").foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                .padding()
                .contextMenu {
                    Button("Switch") {
                        onChange()
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the need to long-press makes the menu hard to discover, so I prefer not to use that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the `ContentView` was a subview with a year & month Int variables. Setting an `id` on the `ScrollView` using these made the issue vanish.